# Jquery Mouseover - e is not defined

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I built my own Jquery tooltip function, it worked for 3 months really good, but now (I don't know why) I get an error: `"e is not defined"`

Can anybody tell me why?

[Example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAkMP/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define your code to use variable `event` to receive the event object:

```
$('.tip').live('mouseenter mousemove mouseleave', function(event) {
```

You initially use the `event` variable:

```
if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
```

However you then change to using the variable `e`:

```
var sc_w = e.pageX + 100;
```

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't work, because you have never defined `e`.

Answer (score 3):

Since your function has `event` parameter not `e`.

```
$('.tip').live('mouseenter mousemove mouseleave', function (event)  
{
    // ...
}
```